# Multiple Loops running together

Tags: php

```
 $a_forms = array("a_GG", "a_FF");
 $sql = "SELECT name, field FROM categories WHERE enabled = '1' ";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $Others = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Other_names[] = $row['name'];
    $Other_fields[] = $row['db_field'];
}


  for ($i=0;$i<count($a_forms);$i++) {   
    if ($a_forms[$i] == "a_FF") {

        $dforms_sql = "SELECT * 
                        FROM a_FF 
                        where id=".$id;                                                              

        $dforms_result = mysqli_query($con,$dforms_sql);

        while ($forms_row = mysqli_fetch_array($dforms_result)) {
            for ($i=0; $i<count($Other_fields); $i++) {

                echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>".$Other_names[$i]."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    } elseif ($a_forms[$i] == "a_GG") {
        $dforms_sql = "SELECT * 
                        FROM a_GG where id=".$id;                                                                
        $dforms_result = mysqli_query($con,$dforms_sql);
        while($forms_row = mysqli_fetch_array($dforms_result)) {
            echo 'Other cool stuff';
        }
    }
} //END (first) For Loop
```

So, for some reason, if that second for loop, $Other_field is there it will only show the IF statement for a_FF. But if the array = a_FF and a_GG and the for loop for $other_field is NOT there it displays them both. So it's obviously that for loop that is breaking something, I have no idea what though. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: This question is bit unclear! Can you evaluate it more?

Comment: Maybe if you showed us an example of `$First_fields` and `Other_fields` it would help us work out whats going on here

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edited to show those values and make more sense

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? It seems like an overly complicated solution. Your variables are horribly named which makes debugging harder. Maybe show us the problem you're trying to solve and not your attempted solution.

Comment: I just made the variable make a bit more sense @waterloomatt. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @waterloomatt. I am trying to accomplish this, if a_forms == a_FF and a_GG it displays the info in both the if statements. However, if it DOES equal both. It seems to ONLY display the a_FF statement because of the the second FOR loops for $other_fields. If I take that out, it shows both, leave it in and it only shows the first IF.

Comment: you are overwriting `$i` in the second for loop. Change that to `$j` or something..

Comment: @Jeff Simple and it worked, I can't believe I didnt think of that.

Comment: and in here `$id` is not defined (possibly somewhere above I  guess)

Comment: @TaLeNT_ I guess all of us oversee/do stupid stuff every now and then. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yes above it was @Jeff You fixed the issue already. I appreciate it, and sorry I didnt think of that.

Comment: `$row['db_field']` wont exist, but `$row['field']` just might

Comment: So `$Other_fields[]` will be empty, which explains your issue I think

Comment: That should have generated an error !!!! Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.